# Service based Android application on Google Play Store

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, google-play

I'm developing an application which will consists only of a few services and no activities (i.e. no UI)
Basically I want to have 2 to 3 services to be running in the background right from when user installs the application on his/her device.

I have a few questions over this:

1. How will my services start after application installation? My `BroadcastReceiver` should be listening to which event?
2. How can I package my application to deploy it application on Googly Play Store?

Comment: As zmbq mentions in his/her answer, it is not possible to register a `BroadcastReceiver` in later versions of Android without some form of user action. In other words, you MUST provide a launcher `Activity` that the user will start manually to enable other application components. The reason for this is to prevent malware being installed without a user knowing. In saying that, even on older versions of Android where it was possible to do such things, it is bad practice to install any software which doesn't allow the user the option to 'activate' it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that on newer Androids. Android specifically requires user interaction before starting up services - the user will need to physically start your application. And if your application doesn't show anything, the user is going to be very confused.

So create one Activity explaining the user what has just happened, and register your receivers there.